# how to prevent my function inside the setinterval running duplicate/twice/thrice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, setinterval

i am using setInterval so that my queue is always updating or checking for updates. Here is what i've got. In my code, i have a setInterval and inside the setInterval i have a function named `check_getqueue` and inside the function of `check_getqueue` i have a function named `refresh_afterdel` which i saw in my console running sometimes twice,thrice or sometimes it behaves good which only run once. How can i prevent this problem?

Here is my setInterval which i put it inside my select box:

```
$('#myclinic_id').change(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    lastQueueID = 0;
    $("#boxqueue").empty();
    var selectedClinicID = $(this).val();
    clinicID = selectedClinicID; 
    statusClinic(clinicID, userID);
    show_patients(clinicID, userID);

    if(selectedClinicID != "0" || selectedClinicID != undefined){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    check_getqueue(clinicID, userID); 
    }, 4000);  
    }
});
```

If my user selects from my select box, it will satisfies the arguments of `check_getqueue` function and starts the setInterval function to run every miniseconds. Now the purpose of my check_getqueue is it is a function that checks my queue everytime there are updates or changes. If it has changes or updates, the div will be automaticaly refresh because i put div refresher inside the check_getqueue function which the function named `refresh_after_del`. My check_getqueue function is always running where if there is no update, it continuously runs. Here is the whole code for check_getqueue:

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
var tmpCountQ = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        tmpCountQ.push(data[i]['queue_id']);
      };
      if(typeof lastCon[0] != "undefined")
      {
        for(j=0;j < tmpCountQ.length;j++)
        {
          if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            refresh_afterdel(clinicID, userID);
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          } 
        } 
      }
      else
      {
       lastCon = tmpCountQ;
      }
      // console.log("lastCon "+lastCon)
      // console.log("tmpCountQ "+tmpCountQ);
    }
  });
}
```

inside the check_getqueue function ,  this `refresh_afterdel(clinicID, userID);` clears the div everytime there was a changes in my queue by satisfying the conditions inside the check_getqueue function.

Now i am getting a problem with these, because every time i got changes in my data, sometimes this refresh_after_del in my console runs twice/thrice and also inside my refresh_after_del , i have a clear div : `$("#boxqueue").empty();` so that i dont have a problem if it runs twice/thrice , but it doesn't. It displays my data multiple if it runs twice and thrice it triples my data (ONLY IN VIEW), but if i manually refresh it, it gives me the correct data.

Here is my full code for refresh_after_del:

```
function refresh_afterdel(getClinicID, userID) {
 $("#boxqueue").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/get_patients_refresh/"+getClinicID+"/"+userID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length>0) {
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              $('#boxqueue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                  '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                  '<div class="col-sm-5">'+'<small>Patient ID: <label id="patientID">'+data[i]['patient_id']+'</label></small>'+''+'<button onclick="checkstatus('+data[i]['patient_id']+');" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs ">View History</button>'+'<button onclick="removequeue('+data[i]['queue_id']+');this.disabled=true;" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnmarg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Remove &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                  '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
            };            
          }
        }
  });  
}
```

Comment: It's a too long read for me, but just to give a quick hints (if I got this correctly) : 1: are you sure you have `var interval;` defined outside? 2: instead of looping... could you call `check_getqueue` inside the AJAX success callback as timeout (and use variables instead of params)? 3: ... have you tried to use `cache: false` in your $ajax?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes sir, i've declared var interval outside of my function . sorry forgot to put it. . i dont understand about (2: could you call check_getqueue inside the AJAX success callback (use variables instead of params))

Comment: Do you mean `$('#boxqueue').append()` runs multiple time, but `$("#boxqueue").empty();` does not? Or your want it to run once only for every change in `'#myclinic_id'`

Comment: @PM. hello sir, my only problem is , it multiplies in my view, and when i saw it in my console, i found that refresh_after_del runs twice. and i dont know why it duplicates? first i empty my div before putting anything.

Comment: Your `refresh_afterdel` will keep running once your change event get fired for `#myclinic_id` because your are clearing interval and starting it again in change event handler only. If you want it to be just one time activity, i.e. you want to update your view only when value in `#myclinic_id` changes then you need not to have it in setinterval. And if you want it to run continuously then your implementation looks good, and every time `$("#boxqueue").empty();` should get called when `append()` gets called. Put messages in console on each step to debug it.

Comment: @PM. it's not about changing #myclinic_id, its about from the function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) where , if there are changes in the queue from the database, it will automatically refresh my div, empty and append again, it gives me correct data, but it duplicates sometimes, sometimes not, sometimes thrice

Comment: OK, got it now. Just try to put ` $("#boxqueue").empty();` before your for loop of success callback in `refresh_afterdel` function.

Comment: hello sir @PM. take a look in my function refresh_after_del, i already put $("#boxqueue").empty(); at it's first in the function before executing anything. Do i need to duplicate it?

Comment: Yes, thats right, I am not sure, but success is the one who is appending content, so it should be the one who should clear it. Also if for some unknown reason, your success getting called multiple times ( I don't see any reason for that)

Comment: @PM. thanks sir, it solves my problem. by just putting $("#boxqueue").empty(); before loop, lol. but is it okay? in my approach? in my console, i got two refresh_after_del function running sometimes and sometimes thrice, sometimes just running once is what i want. ?

Comment: That's because of multiple calls due to function being called by another function (which is inside setInterval). So your function get called in after every 2 seconds for example, but your first request was not completed yet and you have sent another request so each success callback will append the content whereas it's clear has been called even before the append. So sequence could be: Clear(), append(), clear(),clear(), append(), append() and so on.

Comment: so is it okay to this situation sir? that i only empty the div before the loop or how can i do that you said about complete ? or prevent multiple run?